# Ubuntu flashes with a black screen without getting logged in

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login, lightdm, gdm

I was installing drivers for Nvidia GPU where I stopped lightdm to do so.

The drivers were installed through shell (ctrl+alt+f4) which I could verify.

And then I tried to login to my ubuntu desktop. It looped back to the same login screen.

I followed the steps mentioned here

[ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop#223634)

But none seemed to work. I even uninstalled and reinstalled lightdm again. But didnt work. Then I purged and installed gdm through **sudo apt-get purge lightdm && sudo apt-get install gdm**

After this when I rebooted back, my login screen isn't appearing too and black screen is flashing continuously. **I can't get access to my shell too now** through ctrl+alt+f4 (f4 in my system).

I tried sshing to this system from another system but no hope.

Please help!

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Comment: Everything you did is wrong. You installed drivers a wrong way. There was no need to install gdm, etc. Now you broke your system. Restore it form a backup. You have no backup? Then you have to re-install it.

Comment: I could resolve flashing screen by removing gdm and configuring lightdm again from root shell in recovery mode. But it is still getting stuck in login loop. I tried uninstalling drivers and logging in but doesnt seem to work.